# Using signal_timeout for Update function

Tags: gtk, sfml, gtkmm

I am planning to use gtkmm to develop a game. I will use SFML with it (I found a way to make an SFML widget online).

Games need to have an "Update" function that updates the state of the world -- physics, processing of input and more. The point is, the gtk main loop is blocking - I can't override it. But I can connect a timer signal (using signal_timeout) and set it to repeat every 0 milliseconds with max priority -- this is for my Update method.
This is what I'm talking about: https://developer.gnome.org/glibmm/stable/classGlib_1_1SignalTimeout.html

Is this an acceptable way to do this? Any other better way? Or isn't gtk supposed to be used like this?

Another way I had in mind was to have a separate thread to run the Update function. But then I will need to synchronize the threads using a mutex which adds overhead and possibly unnecessary complexity.